# How to order a php array based on custom value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following php array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["POSITION"]=>
    string(6) "Marketer"
    ["FIRSTNAME"]=>
    string(7) "John1"
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(13) "example1@mail.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["POSITION"]=>
    string(10) "Designer"
    ["FIRSTNAME"]=>
    string(6) "John2"
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(29) "example2@mail.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["POSITION"]=>
    string(7) "CEO"
    ["FIRSTNAME"]=>
    string(6) "John3"
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(21) "example3@mail.com"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["POSITION"]=>
    string(10) "Developer"
    ["FIRSTNAME"]=>
    string(5) "John4"
    ["EMAIL"]=>
    string(25) "example4@mail.com"
  }
}
```

I want to reorder it based on [POSITION] column as follows:

1. CEO
2. Marketer
3. Developer
4. Designer

How can I do this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Put those values in an array. Then use `array_search($element['POSITION'], $position_array)` as the values to compare in your ordering function that you call in `usort()`.

Comment: Even better, make it an associative array that maps the position names to their order values, and compare that.

Comment: @Barmar I have the Positions in an array but unable to understand how to write the `usort()` ordering function. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the positions in an array, then use this in the comparison function in `usort()`.

```
$positions = [
    'CEO' => 1,
    'Marketer' => 2,
    'Developer' => 3,
    'Designer' => 4
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($positions) {
    return $positions[$a['POSITION']] - $positions[$b['POSITION']];
})
```